# PHP actions with multiple Buttons resetting others

Tags: php, post, button, input, isset

here you see my code example:

```
<?php
session_start();
$arbeit = $_GET["arbeit"];
echo "Angelegte Prüfung:  ";
echo $arbeit;

$damen = 0;
$herren = 0;
if (array_key_exists('add_Fem',$_POST)) {
    $damen = 1; // BESETZT DAMEN
}
elseif (array_key_exists('sub_Fem',$_POST)) {
    $damen = 0; // Reset counter
}
elseif (array_key_exists('add_Mal',$_POST)) {
    $herren = 1; // BESETZT HERREN
}
elseif(array_key_exists('sub_Mal',$_POST)) {
    $herren = 0; // Reset counter
}
?>

<form method='post'>
    <input name='add_Fem' type="submit" value='Damen' class="button">
</form>
<form method='post'>
    <input name='sub_Fem' type="submit" value='Reset Damen' class="button">
    <h3><em>
            <?php
            if ($damen == 1) {
                echo "DAMEN BESETZT!";
            } else {
                echo "DAMEN FREI!";
            }
            ?>
        </em></h3>
</form>
<form method='post'>
    <input name='add_Mal' type="submit" value='Herren' class="button">
</form>
<form method='post'>
    <input name='sub_Mal' type="submit" value='Reset Herren' class="button">
    <h3><em>
            <?php
            if ($herren == 1) {
                echo "HERREN BESETZT!";
            } else {
                echo "HERREN FREI!";
            }
            ?>
        </em></h3>
</form>
```

the problem is, when i'm try to set both to 1(male and female) the other variable gets reset to 0. And i dont know why they are affect each other!

Also PHP isset not solves my problem, same situation, that was my first try.
I hope you can give me some advice.
Thank you

Comment: _"And i dont know why they are affect each other!"_ - they don't. Each time you submit one of those forms, a new _instance_ of your script is executed, and the variables only live as long as that script instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that makes absolutely sence! But how i solve the problem, should i store the values in a table in a database and read them on every event/klick? Or should i use a cookie?

Comment: There are multiple different ways. You could also store a submitted value into the _session_, so that you still have it available the next time the script runs. Or you could also send it again with the "next" form you are submitting, by putting it into a hidden input field.

Comment: THANK YOU! Storing in a $_SESSION is working well!